# How to create a Facebook account

Tags: facebook

I am not able to create a Facebook account. Whenever I try to create an account, my wife’s Facebook account is opening. In other words, if I type my e-mail address into Facebook, my wife’s Facebook account opens.

Comment: Make sure your email address isn't associated with your wife's account. As far as I know, a single email address cannot have multiple Facebook accounts.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your wife’s Facebook account has been created using your email, so try with another email or ask your wife to remove your email from her account. Then create your account using your email address.

Facebook uses email addresses as username, so it allows to create only one account from one email.

Answer (score 0):

Start the browser in 'Secure mode'/'Incognito mode' or remove all cookies belonging to facebook.com. Or use a different browser alltogether. You could also logon as a different user first on your operating system of choice.

Google Chrome has since version 38 a new feature: [Share Chrome with other people](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824?hl=en) that you could also use to have separated sessions between different users on the same computer. That could help making sure that either you or family members don't use each others settings, including cookies/stored passwords etc.